# CoreImage CIDotScreen on iOS

Tags: ios, ios6, core-image, cifilter

I'm trying to use CIDotScreen in an iOS app. CIDotScreen should be supported under iOS 6, however when I create a filter with:

`[CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIDotScreen" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, beginImage, kCIInputCenterKey...`

The compiler complains on `kCIInputCenterKey`not being available on iOS.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**kCIInputCenterKey**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIFilter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kCIInputCenterKey)

```
A key for a CIVector object that specifies the center of the area, as x and y- coordinates, to be filtered.

Available in OS X v10.5 and later. Not available in iOS.
```

[***Availables Keys for input parameters to filters in iOS.***](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIFilter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003960-RH2-SW4)

1. kCIOutputImageKey;
2. kCIInputBackgroundImageKey;
3. kCIInputImageKey;
4. kCIInputVersionKey;

So we need to accept the compiler's complaint